# how send file with request in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

hi guys i stack in this i used 2 packages http and dio and after 2 days of trying codes i don't find one work 
so i used that with packag dio i wanna send file with request

the problem is here ""dio.post(""   they don't find post in the package

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart' as dio;

dio.FormData formData=new dio.FormData.fromMap({
  "file": await dio.MultipartFile.fromFile(imagePath,filename: imageName),
  "description": "fghfghfghfgh",
  "type": "Profile",
  "selected": "YES",
  "category_id": "3",
});
dio.Response response= await dio.post("https://top-food.coders-ries/images/create", body: formData);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was in file extention not found so i set it with mime liberary and the code is below

```
   Dio dio =new Dio();
      final formData = FormData.fromMap({
        "description": "descriptoin",
        "type": "Profile",
        "selected": "YES",
        "food_id": idOfFood,
      });
      //build the file
      final mimeTypeData = mime.lookupMimeType(filePath, headerBytes: [0xFF, 0xD8]).split('/');
      final file = await MultipartFile.fromFile(filePath, filename: 'image', contentType: MediaType(mimeTypeData[0], mimeTypeData[1]));
      MapEntry<String, MultipartFile> mapEntry =MapEntry(file.filename, file);
      //add the file to request
      formData.files.add(mapEntry);
      Response requestImage = await dio.post("https://top-food.coders-artists.com/api/foods/images/create", data: formData,);`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this please?:

```
    import 'package:dio/dio.dart'

    postData() async{
        Response response;
        Dio dio = Dio();
        FormData formData=new FormData.fromMap({
        "file": await MultipartFile.fromFile(imagePath,filename: imageName),
        "description": "fghfghfghfgh",
        "type": "Profile",
        "selected": "YES",
        "category_id": "3",});
        response= await dio.post("https://top-food.coders-ries/images/create", data: formData);
}
```

Comment: this what iv write !! and >>>>post<<<<  they don't find it

Comment: Oh sorry I missed that part check my answer again.

Comment: I made all of them in a function to make it more clear, if you import dio "as dio" you are getting this error, you need to import it as it is then defind Dio dio = Dio(); to use it as dio.post also in this way you don't need to use dio.Formdata etc you can use them as itselves. I tried the code I gave and it works. I hope that helps.